# Will the MyMonero app support Android versions older than 6.0 (Marshmallow)?

Tags: security, mymonero, android-wallet

I understand that the Bitcoin [Breadwallet](https://breadwallet.com/) only supports Android versions 6.0 and above because of its support for hardware encryption inside the device.

With privacy and security being a core focus for Monero can we expect the same policy for the [soon to be released](https://twitter.com/fluffypony/status/873589961106366466) MyMonero app?